# this php form pass validation even when the fields were blank

Tags: php, html, css, function, mysqli

please can anyone help me to point the error in this code?.Am new to php
  The form submit to database successfully and at the same time displaying
  validations errors,when it suppose to pass validation before submitting
  to mysql        db. for example, when a field is empty,it displays 
  error saying the field is       empty and at the same time is inserted
   into the database.

```
    <?php 
    require_once("validation_function.php");

    $errors=array();
    $message = "";
    $username= "";
    $password= "";

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

     // open a connection to the database
     include("db_connect.php");
     // initialize variables with form data.

     $username =trim($_POST["username"]);
     $password =trim($_POST["password"]);
      //validations


      $field_required= array("username", "password");
        foreach($field_required as $field){
        $value= trim($_POST[$field]);
          if(!has_presence($value)){
           $errors[$field]= ucfirst($field) . " can not be blank";  
           }     
       }

        $field_required_max = array("username"=>30,"password"=>8);
        foreach($field_required_max as $field=> $max){
          $value=trim($_POST[$field]);
             if(!has_max_lenght($value,$max)){
            $errors[$field]= ucfirst($field) . " is too long";   
            }

         }


       $query = "INSERT INTO test (";
       $query .= " username, password";
       $query .= ") VALUES (";
       $query .= " '{$username}', '{$password}' ";
       $query .= ")";
       $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

      if($result==1){
          echo "records inserted successfully";
       }else{
         die("data base query failed " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

          if(isset($connection)){ mysqli_close($connection); }  

    }
       ?>

     <html lang="en">
       <head>
         <title>single page form with validations</title>
     </head>
      <body>
       <?php echo form_errors($errors);?>
          <form action="form_with_validation.php" method="post">
            <p>username <input type="text" name="username" value ="" />
           </p> 
         <p>password <input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank u very much. It worked perfectly. God bless you, your family and all that has contributed to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your errors in the **$errors** variable, but you haven't checked if an error exists.

Before inserting into database, you need to check if there are any errors.

```
.... Other code ....
foreach($field_required_max as $field=> $max){
    /* Statements */ 
}

/* $errors contains the error messages */
/* Insert into database if no errors are present */

if (!$errors) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO test (";
    .....   
    $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

    if ($result==1) {
        echo "records inserted successfully";
    } else {
         die("data base query failed " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(empty($errors))
{
 $query = "INSERT INTO test (";
       $query .= " username, password";
       $query .= ") VALUES (";
       $query .= " '{$username}', '{$password}' ";
       $query .= ")";
       $result= mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

      if($result==1){
          echo "records inserted successfully";
       }else{
         die("data base query failed " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

}
```

Comment: This will work. pleas try and tell me what is not working

Comment: Well, your code checked $error instead of $errors. Now it seems ok.

Comment: Ya, I checked that later and edited it. But I suggest you that please concentrate on logic. If you would have tried that you could have found the mistake with variable name.